# Sending date from json ajax to webapi shows value 1/1/0001

Tags: jquery, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I have a jquery post ajax call where I pass a model in which there are properties defined including a datetime field.

This datetime field is passed using moment.js. In jquery when I check the value it comes out fine. But when I check the same value in my WebApi call, that same date field shows value as 1/1/0001.

Following is my jquery code:

```
var model = {
    "ID": 0,
    "DocNumber": $('#txtDocNo').val(),
    "DocDate": moment($('#txtDocDate').val()).format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
    "Amount": $('#txtAmt').val(),
    "Items": arrErrorData
};
function PostSync(targetUrl, model) {
var result = null;
$.ajax({
    url: targetUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            result = data;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        result = data.statusText;
    }       
});

return result;
```

}

When I check my date here in the model, it shows the correct format and value. But when I check in my WebApi method it shows 1/1/0001.

Following is my WebApi method:

```
public void Post([FromBody]InvoiceDetails InvoiceDetails)
    {
        _itemsbs.Add(InvoiceDetails);
    }
```

Any ideas or suggestions of how I can rectify it, would be great.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the date format to below. This should address your webapi.

```
moment($('#txtDocDate').val()).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
```

Answer (score 0):

change your model to

```
var model = {
"ID": 0,
"DocNumber": $('#txtDocNo').val(),
"DocDate": $('#txtDocDate').val(),
"Amount": $('#txtAmt').val(),
"Items": arrErrorData
```

};

OR
you want to formatted date in your API model
Then pls change ur API DateTime object to String

Answer (score 0):

Parse your Date string into DATE Object before convert it into JSON string. At server API receive this Date string as Date object.

```
var model = {
    "ID": 0,
    "DocNumber": $('#txtDocNo').val(),
    "DocDate": new Date($('#txtDocDate').val()),
    "Amount": $('#txtAmt').val(),
    "Items": arrErrorData
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `MM/DD/YYYY` format for the date in the below way:

`moment($('#txtDocDate').val()).format('MM/DD/YYYY')`

This should populate the date properly in your API object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I resolved it like this:

```
var model = {        
    "ID": 0,
    "DocNumber": $('#txtDocNo').val(),
    "DocDate": new Date(moment($('#txtDocDate').val())),
    "Amount": $('#txtAmt').val(),
    "Items": arrErrorData
};
```